# MSIL OpCode.Ldftn vs RuntimeMethodHandle

Tags: c#, .net, clr, cil

`OpCode.Ldftn` and `RuntimeMethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer` have the same value on a 32 bit platform but on x64 they don't.

Using the value returned by `ldftn` I can perform a `calli` instruction on both x86 and x64 platforms.

The value of `RuntimeMethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer` is not valid for `calli` on x64.

Why?

Comment: Which runtime are you using? Core CLR? .NET Framework? Mono?

Comment: .net frame work 4 +

Comment: They seem the same for me on both x86 and x64. You're going to need to show your code.

Comment: @Iridium I used `assembly builder` to get `ldftn` value and it differs from `RuntimeMethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer`

Comment: You should add the code for your scenarios to your question. Currently the question is very hard to answer - there is already a close vote.

Comment: ok I will put all codes .. after an hour.

Comment: Any update here?

Comment: yes there is.. I will update the question with full code.. but in last test .. ldftn and MethodHandle returns the same value in single assembly .. but for referenced assembly .. they differ